# What is this heavy file (ziY7hRQ8) in Wordpress instalation

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I realized recently the presence of a file named "ziY7hRQ8" in one of my Wordpress installations. No other installation has such file and moreover, it is quite heavy. Here's a sceenshot:

[image: A screenshot displaying the file in question on top]

I've tried downloading and opening it with the text editor but it's illegible. Besides it has no extension. Any ideas what is this could be about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is not from WordPress. You can delete it.
Sometimes this kind of file may appear if your site is malware-infected or it may be a corrupted file.
So, after deleting that file you should scan your whole site for safety.

Comment: I've deleted it and everything works fine for now. I hope it was a corrupted file since this site is very new. Thank you.